# Create and write a file chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome packaged app and i want to create and write files with a path local to my code [i don't want user to choose where to save it]. `chrome.storage` have limited storage and `chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry` make the user choose where to save it.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

PS: also, is there a way to use local file as part of your script? eg: user enter `~/desktop/whatever/path.mp3` how can u play that audio file without reading it? [link to audio tag?]. [when i try it leads me to `/chrome-extensions/ajdhshfusdkscnnkjas/~/desktop/whatever/path.mp3`]

Comment: `chrome.storage` is not limited with `unlimitedStroage` permission.

Comment: AFAIK you will always run into problems if you want to silently access the local file system. It's meant so users don't have to worry their computer will get hacked every time they install an extension. Re-consider the other storage options and use the `unlimitedStorage` permission. You can always get the user to manually save specific files they want complete access to later (e.g. using _"download"_ or `chooseEntry`).

Comment: @Xan if you declare this permission in `manifest.json` does that mean you have unlimited `chrome.storage` - `sync` and `local`?

Comment: `local` only. `sync` always has hard limits.

Comment: than what does `unlimitedStorage` give you permission to do?

Comment: Unlimited quota for all local storage APIs, including web databases, [HTML5 `FileSystem` API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/), etc.

Comment: if HTML5 FileSystem API limited to `http` and `https` will chrome packaged app be able to use this api? also when you request the databse what do you put as the size of the database?

Comment: HTML5 FileSystem is not limited to http(s) origins; apps can use it as a virtual private filesystem without any prompts. `unlimitedStorage` allows you to request any size without confirmation from user.